# Changing the samesite session cookie attribute in a spring webflux application

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, session-cookies, spring-webflux

I am trying to change the same site attribute of my springboot application using `WebSessionIdResolver` as described here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-webflux-custom-cookie.html

```java
@Configuration
public class CookieConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public WebSessionIdResolver webSessionIdResolver() {
        CookieWebSessionIdResolver resolver = new CookieWebSessionIdResolver();
        resolver.addCookieInitializer(builder -> builder.sameSite("None"));
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is going, when debugging I can see the bean being initialized,but on every http call a session cookie is written with the default sameSite attribute "Lax", and the default `CookieWebSessionIdResolver.cookieInitializer` being null.

Comment: This is for using Spring Session for writing its cookies, it is not for Spring WebFlux for writing all other cookies.

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to do : changing the spring session cookie.

Comment: That won't work with this as this is for Spring Session **not** Spring WebFlux. So unless you are using Spring Session together with Spring WebFlux this won't work.

Comment: ah ok, I just need to add spring session to the app pom.xml ? Or is there a way to do this with webflux/spring security only ?

Comment: No. If you aren't using Spring Session this config won't work. I suggest you readup on what Spring Session is (and you probably aren't using it of you need to ask). So this config, nor adding the dependency, will make it work. You have to configure Spring WebFlux **not** Spring Session. You are doing the latter and expect it to work for cookies written by the former, that is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this adding 'spring-session-core' dependency and using the following config :

```java
@EnableSpringWebSession
@Configuration
public class CookieConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public WebSessionIdResolver webSessionIdResolver() {
        CookieWebSessionIdResolver resolver = new CookieWebSessionIdResolver();
        resolver.addCookieInitializer(builder -> builder.sameSite("None"));
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveMapSessionRepository reactiveSessionRepository() {
        return new ReactiveMapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    }
}
```